# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, null

Tags: c#, object-reference

i keep getting this error message: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
  private static void GetIPInfo(User user)
  {
      string ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();

      string city = string.Empty;
      string region = string.Empty;
      string country = string.Empty;
      double? latitude = -1.00;
      double? longitude = -1.00;

      LocationTools.GetLocationFromIP(ipAddress, out city, out region, out country, out latitude, out longitude);

      user.IPAddress = user.IPAddress; **//error is pointing here**
  }
```

Do i need to instantiate something?

Would it be something like this to solve the problem?

```
 user.IPAddress new user.IPAddress = user.ipAddress;
```

Comment: Firstly, you're assigning something to itself which is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way you are calling *GetIPInfo(User user)*. It seems that you are passin null as *user*. Maybe you should write something like

```
GetIPInfo(new User());
```

But it is not clear whether User has to be initialized some way, or it is enough to create an empty instance.
Furthermore, I do not understand what you are trying to do with *user.IPAddress = user.IPAddress;* It is an instruction that does not seem to have any effect at all, unless there is some other code in the setter of IPAddress which causes some collateral effect, but this is something I would avoid.

EDIT after your comment:

If I got it right (but I'm not really sure), maybe this is more similar to what you really need:

private static User GetIPInfo()
  {
      User user = new User();

```
  string ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();

  string city = string.Empty;
  string region = string.Empty;
  string country = string.Empty;
  double? latitude = -1.00;
  double? longitude = -1.00;

  LocationTools.GetLocationFromIP(ipAddress, out city, out region, out country, out latitude, out longitude);

  user.IPAddress = ipAddress; 
  // other code to fill the other fields of User

  return user;
}
```

Then you can call it and get a new instance of User that you can assign to a variable or use as you like.

Comment: GetIPInfo(user0); im using this further at the top, im trying to add the IPAddres for that user who likes the facebook page which is then added to the database, at the moment its null values. It was adding the user info before i tried adding ipAddress etc to the columns in that table.

Comment: GetIPInfo(newUser); that is what i should have set it to, so now it is capturing the IP Address when i debug in to my code, schoolboy error, A second pair of eyes is useful. Thanks Guys :)

Answer (score 2):

What exactly did you expect this statement to achieve:

```
user.IPAddress = user.IPAddress;
```

I'd expect it to be *at best* a no-op. As it happens, it seems that the value for the `user` variable is null.

It's not clear what the method is meant to do, but presumably if `user` is null then the request is unauthenticated. It's odd that a `GetXyz` method has a `void` return type. Should it be `PopulateIPInfo` for example? In that situation it sounds like it would be a bug to be passed a null reference - but you really need to decide what the method is meant to do... It's unlikely that creating a new `User` instance *inside that method* is going to be useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
user = new User; // Or whatever user is supposed to be

user.IPAddress = ipAddress; // Now you can assign an ip address to this property
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jon pointed out, your `user` seems to be null. I would think the problem is in the calling method, not in `GetIPInfo`. You might want to add some argument checking to your methods. Also, I think that this method looks odd, but I might just not have the proper context to understand why it looks like it does.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` throws `System.NullReferenceException` – `“Object reference not set to an
instance of an object.”` -error if IP address is not provided in the request. So you should check if the statement throws an exception.

Comment: "if IP address is not provided in the request"? Could you explain that one?